# Why does captcha occur for Stack Overflow for Teams?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams, captcha

I just received a captcha request while using Stack Overflow for Teams.

Assuming that the people who can sign up for the team are restricted, why is it necessary to check if I'm a human being?

[image]

Comment: I've been experiencing various stability issues with the overall services throughout the day today (not related to Teams), for example, extremely slow loading of pages, failure to execute some requests, multiple "we're offline for maintenance" messages, etc. So, it might be related to that. It looks like they might be fighting [another wave of DDoS attacks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376060/348196).

Comment: I assume the team you're referring to is a paid team?  (since anyone could theoretically sign up for a free team if they were trying to DDoS Stack Overflow)

Comment: @RyanM I assume it's paid. I'm not doing the paying...

Comment: @41686d6564 In Australia, there's been a lot of cyberattacks over the past few weeks, most notably Optus. Have there been a lot happening where you are?

Comment: Some speculation: same code might cover both teams and non-teams, or paid and unpaid; or just because an account is paid for doesn't preclude the possibility of its use in DDoS, e.g. if credentials were leaked by/stolen from the account owner.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine [stackstatus](https://www.stackstatus.net/) has indicated intermittent service problems since the beginning of this month, for me it usually happens after 0UTC...